# Recursive HTTP-requests in Scala

Tags: scala, jackson, gitlab, gitlab-api

I need to do recursive requests and then collect all models into one List, but not understand how to do it. Please tell me am I thinking right way?

```
package kindSir.main

import dispatch.Defaults._
import dispatch._
import kindSir.models._
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

object ApplicationMain extends App {

  def fetchMergeRequests(startPage: Int = 1): Future[List[MergeRequest]] = {
    val requestsUrl = url(s"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/gitlab-org%2Fgitlab-ce/merge_requests?state=opened&per_page=3&page=${startPage}")
    Http(requestsUrl).map { res =>
      (parse(res.getResponseBody), res.getHeader("X-Next-Page").toInt) match {
        case (list@JArray(_), nextPage: Int) =>
          val currentList: List[MergeRequest] = MergeRequest.parseList(list).get
          val nextPageListFuture: Future[List[MergeRequest]] = fetchMergeRequests(nextPage)
          // And how to merge these two lists?
        case (list@JArray(_), _) => MergeRequest.parseList(list).get
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"No merge requests for project found")
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Interesting. Were you explicitly asked to generate recursive http requests, like in a classroom setting? Or is there some business problem you're solving with this mechanism?

Comment: Consider this: http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you're dealing with here is that you're trying to combine data you already have (`List[MergeRequest]`) with the data you'll retrieve in future (`Future[List[MergeRequest]]`). There are a few things you need to do to handle this scenario:

- Use `flatMap` instead of `map` on result of the HTTP request. This allows you to make further HTTP requests inside the recursion but map them back to a single `Future`.
- Call `map` on the result of the recursion `fetchMergeRequests(nextPage)` to combine the data you already have with the future data from the recursion.
- Wrap the other list in `Future.successful()` because `flatMap` requires all the pattern matches to return a `Future` — except for the exception.

I'm not familiar with the libraries you are using so I haven't tested it, but I think your code should work like this:

```
def fetchMergeRequests(startPage: Int = 1): Future[List[MergeRequest]] = {
  val requestsUrl = url(s"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/gitlab-org%2Fgitlab-ce/merge_requests?state=opened&per_page=3&page=${startPage}")
  Http(requestsUrl).flatMap { res =>
    (parse(res.getResponseBody), res.getHeader("X-Next-Page").toInt) match {
      case (list@JArray(_), nextPage: Int) =>
        val currentList: List[MergeRequest] = MergeRequest.parseList(list).get
        val nextPageListFuture: Future[List[MergeRequest]] = fetchMergeRequests(nextPage)
        nextPageListFuture.map(nextPageList => currentList ++ nextPageList)
      case (list@JArray(_), _) =>
        Future.successful(MergeRequest.parseList(list).get)
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"No merge requests for project found")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @gutch! I used your code to [propose request to open source project kind-sir](https://github.com/answr42/kind-sir/pull/6/files).